# Finding the surface of a triangle in a cartesian cube

Tags: c#, graphics, 3d

I have a 3 dimensional array of bit values (either 0 or 1) representing the X, Y and Z axis (in the range of 0-99) of a cartesian cube. The entire array is initialized to all 0's.

Additionally I have a triangle of points within that cube identified by the following points.

`TriangleA: 
[

       15, 22, 11,

       86, 76, 67,

       45, 51, 91

]`

Marking those three points with a value of 1 would be easy.  My question is this:

How would I mark all of the other coordinates of the surface identified by that triangle with a value of 1 as well?

Basically how would I implement the function:

`public bool IsOnSurfaceOfTriangleA(x, y, z) {`

```
   // Math goes here! :)
```

}

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you plan on accounting for integer precision loss? Unless the triangle is aligned with the axis, it's probably almost certain that the "surface" of the triangle will be "between" the integer points. EDIT: Would it be fine to use integer math everywhere for the calculation (thus have a very jagged triangle?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine if a 3D point is within a triangle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995445/determine-if-a-3d-point-is-within-a-triangle)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a loop that is using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049582/how-to-determine-a-point-in-a-triangle) solution. Simple determine the min and max range and run them in a double for loop(from min till max)

Comment: This looks absolutely perfect in concept, but he's specifically asking about 2d.  Is there a translation that I'm missing to apply it to a 3d problem space?

Comment: Would the same math work if I just replaced the 2d points with 3d vectors or something?

Answer (score 0):

I found this MatLab function that I was able to port over to C# -works great.  Now I need to do this for a whole bunch of meshes all at once, so I'll post that in a separate question.  Thanks for all your help!

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22857-distance-between-a-point-and-a-triangle-in-3d